# Django Form doesn't add new object to ManyToManyField but switch between other

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to update object by adding new user to permission, and if i'm updating it doesn't add user but set other users which have this permission are unselected.

views.py

```
elif(request.POST['custom'] == 'assign'):
    guest = Departments.objects.get(id=request.POST['id'])
    print(request.POST)
    form = AddDepartment()
    form2 = AssignDepartment(data=request.POST, instance=guest)
    if form2.is_valid():
        department = Departments.objects.get(department = 
        form2.cleaned_data['department'])
        print(form2.cleaned_data['user'])
        print(form2.cleaned_data['user'][0].id)

 department.user.add(Person.objects.get(id=form2.cleaned_data['user'][0].id))
form2.save()
```

models.py

```
 department = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='Oddziały', unique=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField('Person', blank=True, verbose_name='Pracownik')
```

Comment: You question is unclear ! You have M2M table between departments and users. `department.user.add(Person.objects.get(id=form2.cleaned_data['user'][0].id))` this performs database query and add data in M2M table. what's wrong with you ?

Comment: Yes I would rather use set, but i've tried almost everything. I found solution I've changed my model. I remove field user from Departments and make M2M field in table Person. It works perfect right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution I've changed my model. I remove field user from Departments and make M2M field in table Person. It works perfect right now.